# Open Modal on page load causing Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to open a modal on page load but I get `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

I know why this is happening because there are many posts about it. I don't know how to fix it though.

I'm using the Material UI [modal](https://material-ui.com/utils/modal/)

I've tried loading it in `componentDidMount`- caused error. I tried also to use onClick and simulate a click to open it, but this did not work - could not get simulation to work. Below is my latest attempt - caused error.

```
<Button onLoad={this.openModal.bind(this)()}>Open Modal</Button>

openModal(e) {
     this.setState({
      open:true
     })
  }
```

I can't seem to get past the error and open the modal on load.

In the Modal file, the modal itself looks like this:

```
 <Button onLoad={this.openModal.bind(this)()}>Open Modal</Button>
 <Modal
         aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
         aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
         open={this.state.open}
         onClose={this.handleClose}
    >
```

In the parent component

```
   <Modal open={this.state.modalState}/> //=> true
```

I tried this as well (with the event handler removed and not being called `this.openModal.bind(this)()`). Got the error

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  this.setState({
      open:this.props.open
    })
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are rending the modal

Comment: added more code

Comment: You need not call the function after you bind it. Remove () after bind. If you need to call the function, use `call` instead of `bind`.

Comment: It doesn't load without that. Tried both ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, for rendering a modal we will use a state to specify is its open or close, If you want to open the modal as soon as the component loads then you can specify the state open as true  by default

for example

```
  Class Example extends React.component {
  construtor(props) {
  super(props)
 this.state = { open: true }
}
render() {
return <Modal open={this.state.open}>{//body goes here}</Modal>
}
}
```

This opens modal by default and you can toggle it depending on your requirement

You are calling `setstate` in `componentdidupdate` with out any conditions this will cause stacklevel too deep error as after setstate the componentwillupdate will be invoked again

If you want you can use `componentdidmount` instead

Comment: Apologies- it seems that this entire thing was a stupid typo as I did not want `componentDidUpdate` but rather the normal `componentDidMount`. Using the proper one fixed it immediately. I would delete this question. However you took the time to compose this answer so I'll mark it as solved instead